# Sum of specific elements in array

Tags: ios, swift

I have a couple of tableviewcells. It has 2 `rate` values 200 and 300 respectively. These 2 values I’m adding to an array like so

```
    let theRateElement = (Int(product?.theRate ?? "") ?? 0)
    rateArray.append(theRateElement)

    self.sumedArr = rateArray.reduce(0, { ($0 + $1)})
```

Now, my `summedArr` will have the value 500

I also have on my `tableviewcell` a picker textfield. The picker gives values from 1 to 10. If I select 2 from the pickerview of first cell, then that 2 will be multiplied with 200 to give 400 & if I select 3 from the pickerview of 2nd tableview cell, then then the value of 300 will become 900 (300*3)

I'm taking the sum of these 2 new values like so...(in picker `didSelectRow`)

```
let finalAmt = fixedRate * totalItems

let theRateElement = finalAmt
updatedRateArray.append(theRateElement)
self.sumedArr = updatedRateArray.reduce(0, { ($0 + $1)})
```

Now `summedArr` will have the value (200*2)+(300*3) = 1300

But what I want to achieve is if I multiply just the 1st value of 200 by 2 to get 400 and keep the 2nd value of 300 as it is then I should get the total as 400+300 = 700. But how to achieve this that I’m not able to figure out.

Comment: Your picker view has 1 to 10 and your array has 2 Element 200 and 300 as you said if you select 2 then 200 *2 and if you select 3 then 300 * 3 now what about other values like if i select 4 from picker ? Did I miss anything ?

Comment: As per my understanding you have picker view for each value row like one picker view for 200 value and other picker view for 300 value and user can select value from picker separately  is it correct ?

Comment: Thanks @JonSnow. The issue could be fixed. Please have a look at my answer..

Comment: Btw, @JonSnow u got it right(in your 2nd comment..)

Answer (score 0):

The issue could be fixed like so...

There is an array which has the initial values of 200 & 300. Now the value with which I will multiply 2, 3 etc. is surely one of the values of the initial array. So that is checked and those values are removed. Now the initial array will be left with those elements which is not multiplied by any number.

The nos. which are multiplied is also stored in an array. Now this array and the initial array are both combined and their elements are added. This finally gives me the sum of numbers multiplied by 2,3,4...etc. and those numbers which are not multiplied which is the desired result..

Comment: Happy to listen that you solved issue but My suggestion is that instead of keep all things separated you should create Array of struct or Array of class which contains all the information , use this array as datasource of your tableview cell and put all items there regarding to  user selection from picker or your values like 200 or 300